# Analytics metrics not match the data adwords

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api

I'm new on stackoverflow , my question is about the google analytics api, I'm using the next metrics in my php project:

**"ga:impressions, ga:CTR, ga:adCost, ga:adClicks, ga:CPC",**

And **ga:keywords** like dimenssion.

Impressions , Clicks and CTR are fine, even Keywords are well, but the problem is that the Cost and CPC not match with the adwords data for my account.

Example:

Results for my adwords account:

*Clicks: 20

Impressions: 2030

CTR: 0.99%

CPC: 17.47 MXN

Cost: 349.33 MXN*

Results for Analytics metrics:

*Clicks: 20

Impressions: 2030

CTR: 0.99%

CPC: 1.19

Cost: 23.85*

As You can see in the example match all metrics , with the exception Cost and CPC.

I searched about this but have not found anything , Can anyone help me or advise me with this problem?

Sorry for my bad English , I'm still practicing and trying to improve.

I hope you can help me , thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that you are running AdWords account in different currency. Ratio between both CPC and Cost in AdW and GA suggest that Analytics might use USD.

More about it at https://www.en.adwords-community.com/t5/Tracking-Reporting/Adwords-cost-incorrect-in-Analytics-currency-issue/td-p/394643